# button group with label on top of each button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to group buttons using btn-toolbar(not using btn-group because I want different buttons) and I also want to add label at top of each button but I am unable to achieve what I am trying to. here is the code snippet.

```html
<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg output_border">A</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg output_border">A</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg output_border">A</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg output_border">A</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg output_border">A</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg output_border">A</button>
</div>
```

[here is picture of what i am expecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7TWY.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution you need. It works as per the image you have shown

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap btn-tool</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .labelarrange1{
        float:left;
        position:relative;
        left:5px;
        top:8px;
        font-size:10px;
    }

    .btn{
        border-radius:0;
        background:powderblue;
        border-radius:0;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="btn-toolbar container" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-1">
          <label class="labelarrange1">Relay 1</label>
          <br>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg">A</button>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-1">
          <label class="labelarrange1">Relay 1</label>
          <br>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg">A</button>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-1">
          <label class="labelarrange1">Relay 3</label>
          <br>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg" style="background:#eee;">O</button>
      </div>
  </div>



</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: good solution works in big screen but on small screen like cellphone it show buttons vertically. Thanks

Comment: To bring responsiveness as per the view port size you need to use `@media rule in css`  for different size screen. I can even help you with that else you visit this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) to understand more.

Comment: Thanks. how can i do if if they are not buttons and just labels.

Comment: You can send me the image. The way you wish to arrange. Definitely we can find a way.

Comment: i have followed http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/list-group-horizontal method for grouping  labels but not able to add heading to each list element

Comment: okay these are grouped headings needs to be added on top of each button right!!.

Comment: ya but i managed to solve it using your answer. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

---

```
<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
  <label>a</label>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg output_border">A</button>
  <label>a</label>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg output_border">A</button>
  <label>a</label>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg output_border">A</button>
  <label>a</label>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg output_border">A</button>
  <label>a</label>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg output_border">A</button>
  <label>a</label>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg output_border">A</button>
</div>
```

i may not be totally correct.. try using some seperation techniques.